# Select amount in CSS selector

Tags: css, shell, scrapy

I am trying to select a price in CSS selector for the following page;

https://www.funda.nl/en/koop/nieuwegein/huis-42656543-wattbaan-22/

The css path that I would like to select is 'strong.object-header__price'. This corresponds to the following line of code in scrapy shell and output:

```
response.css('strong.object-header__price').xpath('normalize-space()').extract()
['€ 675,000 k.k.']
```

However, I would only like to select the amount, 675,000.

For xpath I know how to do this, namely:

```
response.xpath("substring-before(substring(// 
[@id='content']/div/div/div[1]/section[5]/div/dl[1]/dd[1]/span[1]/text(),'3','25'),' 
')").extract()
```

Can someone please advise me how I can do the same steps, but then for the css selector? I cannot find on the internet how this can be done, so therefore this question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few options:

**1.** Select substring (probably what you wanted):

```py
In [1]: price = response.css('.object-header__price::text').get()[2:-5]

In [2]: price
Out[2]: '675,000'
```

**2.** Use replace:

```py
In [1]: price = response.css('.object-header__price::text').get()

In [2]: price = price.replace('€ ', '')

In [3]: price = price.replace(' k.k.', '')

In [4]: price
Out[4]: '675,000'
```

**3.** Use regex

```py
In [1]: import re

In [2]: price = response.css('.object-header__price::text').get()

In [3]: price = re.findall(r'(\d+,\d+)', price)

In [4]: price[0]
Out[4]: '675,000'
```

**4.** Get it from the script:

```py
In [1]: import json

In [2]: price = response.css('head > script[type="application/ld+json"]::text').get()

In [3]: script_data = json.loads(price)

In [4]: script_data['offers']['price']
Out[4]: '675000'
```

Comment: The first 1 seems to do it. Thx for the answer!

Comment: what would be the best method to apply in case that the price can change to a 7-digit number, so for example 1500000

Comment: @error404 For a 7-digit number you can either use method 2 or 4.

Comment: Thank you for your information, it really helps. Now I also want to select the following: class="object-header__subtitle fd-color-dark-3". This corresponds to the zip code, municipality name and neighbourhood. I only want the municipality name of this. Could you indicate how this can be done? It regards the following page: https://www.funda.nl/en/koop/beverwijk/huis-88010325-schans-56/